# How can I change the layout of an error in Joomla?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0, joomla3.1

I am throwing an exception in a controller like this

```
   throw new Exception("Could not save user. Error: " . $user->getError());
```

But the layout of the html that displays the message is not relevant with the layout of my website. So I need to put my hands and change the html of that layout. 
 [image]

How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read this: http://docs.joomla.org/Custom_error_pages

This is: Put an error.php into /templates/your_template/error.php and style it to your wishes.

Answer (score 5):

You really should catch the exception and then convert it to a message using setMessage if you need to tell the user something, otherwise log it and move on.

Also note that getError and setError are both deprecated.

Comment: thank you, your advises are usfull. But I really needed to change the actuall layout of the error message page. That red and white. Custom error pages helped me, I didn't know anything about them. Is there any other way?

Comment: Do you want it to go to an error page? IF you do then the links Bakual provided to creating a custom error page will show you how.  If you just want to show an error in context on a page then do what I said.